# What is ${\rm Aut}\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group, direct-sum

Let $p$ be a prime, what is the automorphism group of $G=\bigoplus_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_p$ (countable infinite direct sum of $\mathbb{Z}_p$)?

I know every permutation of the coordinates will be an automorphism, so $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbb{Z})$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$. I think there will be other automorphisms, because ${\rm Aut}\,\mathbb Z_p\simeq \mathbb Z_{p-1}$, so in each coordinate, we can map a generator to a different generator. Also, we can map a generator in one coordinate to a generator in another coordinate.

Any insight/reference would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For finite sums $\operatorname{Aut} \bigoplus_{i = 1}^n \Bbb Z_p \cong \operatorname{GL}(n, \Bbb Z_p)$.

Comment: The given group is a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb F_p$ of countably infinite dimension. Its automorphism group is $\operatorname{GL}(V)$, though that's not very helpful. The elements can be represented as infinite square matrices with entries in $\mathbb F_p$ which have finitely supported columns and which are invertible (the rows do not need to be finitely supported, e.g., there is a transvection which acts on a basis according to $e_i \mapsto e_i + e_0$ for $i \ne 0$, $e_0 \mapsto e_0$).

Comment: Also, the endomorphism ring $\operatorname{End}(V)$ is given by the same description but without the invertibility condition.

Comment: @SeanEberhard You should write that as an answer.